# Can you get to Eberron via the Dream of the Blue Veil spell?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, eberron

The *dream of the blue veil* spell says:

> You and up to eight willing creatures within range fall unconscious for the spells’ duration and experience visions of another world on the Material Plane, such as Oerth, Toril, Krynn, or Eberron. If the spell reaches its full duration, the visions conclude with each of you encountering and pulling back a mysterious blue curtain. The spell then ends with you mentally and physically transported to the world that was in the visions.

...which seems pretty conclusive, but in *Eberron: Rising from the Last War*, it is clarified that Eberron lies within the Ethereal Plane, not the Material Plane:

> The three progenitor wyrms worked together to form Eberron and its planes as a new cosmic system in the depths of the Ethereal Plane.

Is this a conflict, or does something reconcile these disparate references? Can you travel to Eberron via *dream of the blue veil*?

Answer (score 7):

#### Eberron setting has its own, particular cosmology.

The figure in the section [Planes of Existence](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/erftlw/building-eberron-adventures-the-last-war#PlanesofExistence) (Eberron: Rising from the Last War, ERftLW) clearly states the planet Eberron is in the material plane, but at the same time it seems to be not *the* Material Plane: indeed, there is a sentence that explain the uniqueness of Eberron setting (emphasis mine):

> The planet of Eberron is the heart of its **own** Material Plane.

The initial paragraph of this section states that it is part of the Great Wheel<sup>1</sup> of the universe, but at the same time

> it is fundamentally apart from the rest of the Great Wheel, sealed off from the other planes even while it’s encircled by its **own** wheeling cosmology

This seems to imply that Eberron lives in a *different* material plane, because of "*own*" in the quoted sentences. Together with the second quote provided in the answer, it seems that Eberron setting takes place somewhere in the Great Wheel, it shares some characteristic with other cosmic systems but it has its own rules and place.

#### Eddy, very interesting, but is it on the Ethereal Plane or what?

The information seems to be contradictory, but the same figure cited above shows that the Ethereal plane surrounds the Eberron's Material Plane, following the rules of the DMG (page 48).

A weak escamotage to solve this issue could be adopting a different reading of the quote in the question: the three dragons were in the Ethereal plane when they were creating the cosmic system:

> The three progenitor wyrms worked together *in the depths of the Ethereal Plane* to form Eberron and its planes as a new cosmic system.

#### Can the Dream of the Blue Veil spell allows to travel to Eberron?

In the section [Eberron and the Multiverse](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/erftlw/building-eberron-adventures-the-last-war#EberronandtheMultiverse) one can read (emphasis mine)

> It is theoretically possible to travel between Eberron and other worlds in the multiverse by means of the Deep Ethereal or **various spells designed for planar travel**, but the cosmology of Eberron is specifically designed to prevent such travel, to keep the world hidden away from the meddling of gods, celestials, and fiends from beyond.

Hence, since *Dream of the Blue Veil* spell is designed for planar traveling and there is at least *a* Material Plane on Eberron, such spell can be used to go to Eberron. Note anyway that in the same section of ERftLW we can read that a DM could rule that the barrier formed by the Ring of Siberys is intact, and it is not possible to reach Eberron and its own system from other worlds:

> In your campaign, you might decide that the barrier formed by the Ring of Siberys is intact, and contact between Eberron and the worlds and planes beyond its cosmology is impossible. This is the default assumption of this book

---

<sup>1</sup> Aiming to generate more confusion, in the DMG, page 44, one can read about different cosmological system other than the Great Wheel, the World Tree and the World Axis. Among them there is *The Orrerey*:

> **The Orrery.** All the Inner and Outer Planes orbit the Material Plane, exerting greater or lesser influence on the world as they come nearer and farther. The world of Eberron uses this cosmological model.

Comment: _Hence, since Dream of the Blue Veil spell is designed for planar traveling and there is at least a Material Plane on Eberron, such spell can be used to go to Eberron._ => I'm not sure I agree with this conclusion. The spell mentions _the_ Material Plane, not _a_ Material Plane. My favored reading would be that the spell is designed to navigate within _the current_ Material Plane, but not _to another_ Material Plane, and thus is useless to reach Eberron, but could be used to travel around Eberron.

Comment: @matthieu-m For any material outside of Eberron, distinguishing between "a" Material Plane and "the" Material Plane is meaningless. I wouldn't use authors choosing one over the other in campaigns where it genuinely does not matter as evidence of anything.

Comment: @MatthieuM. Problem is that the PHB says there is just one material plane, while in E:RftLW *seems* to suggest there is another one, or it may be a "section" of the original one but unreachable: it is quite foggy. Anyway, the last quote in the answer taken from the Eberron manual says that the DM could make this world unreachable, disregarding on *which* material plane the planet is.

Answer (score 3):

#### Eberron is on the Material Plane.

The intro to *Eberron: Rising from the Last War* states:

> Every child knows the story of the Progenitor Dragons: Siberys, Eberron, and Khyber. In the dawn of time, these three cosmic beings created thirteen planes of existence, each embodying a concept. **Their final work was the Material Plane**

It goes on the explain that this world they created became Khyber’s prison, and is called Eberron.

So yes, you can reach Eberron with *dream of the blue veil*, since Eberron is on the Material Plane, and because the spell says you can.

Comment: This doesn't quite answer the conflict. It is certainly possible that Eberron was crafted from the material plane and later moved to the Ethereal Plane as described later in the book. That later section also mentions that Eberron has its own "Material Plane" which is seemingly different (maybe?) Than the Material Plane referenced in the DMG.

Comment: @DavidCoffron The way I read it, it just exists in a different place but is no less material than any other.